# $0$-dimensional range in a linear transformation: $\text{Im}(f) \subseteq \text{Kern}(f)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear transformation. I was requested to decide whether it is possible for such transformation to satisfy $\text{Im}(f) \subseteq \text{Kern}(f)$.

The requirement can be rephrased as an implication. $f$ satisfies such property if and only if $f(\textbf{x}) = \textbf{y} \implies f(\textbf{y})=0$; *i.e.* if any element of the range is an element of the kernel.

Upon considering this question, I came to observe it is not possible for $\text{Im}(f), \text{Kern}(f)$ to have equal dimensions, for that would imply the dimension of the domain is an even number. Hence, $\dim\Big(\text{Im}(f) \Big) \in \{0, 1\}$. This consideration took me to contemplate a $0$-dimensional range: something I never thought of or studied before.

Indeed, if we let $f(x, y, z) = (0, 0, 0) = \textbf{0}$, then it is the case that $\text{Im}(f) = \{\textbf{0}\} \subseteq \text{Kern}(f)$, since $\{0\} \in \text{Kern}(f)$ by necessity.

That the rule $f(x, y, z) = (0, 0, 0)$ is linear is trivially observed. So it is not the *linearity* of $f$ which I deem worthy of attention, but rather the fact that such a "null" linear transformation was never mentioned in any of the textbooks I use for studying.

Is such transformation completely trivial, or does it possess any particular property worth noting? On one hand, it seems completely superfluous to speek of a transformation $f$ whose kernel is its domain and always maps to $0$. On the other hand, I imagine such property might be useful under certain circumnstances, as it may be thought of as representing "nullifying" transformations across vector spaces.

Forgive me if the question is too elementary or silly, I'm very new to linear algebra.

Comment: Of course the zero map is a well defined linear transformation, with a trivial range $\{0\}$, and kernel the whole of its domain.

Answer (score 1):

It is required that $f(y) = 0, y = f(x), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Hence $f\circ f (x) = 0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

We should find $f$ such that $f\circ f = 0$. For instance, we write $f$ as
$$
\begin{align}
f\colon \mathbb{R}^3 &\to \mathbb{R}^3  \\
x&\mapsto Ax
\end{align}
$$
where $A$ is a matrix in shape $(3, 3)$. To make $f\circ f = 0$, it suffices to let $A^2 = 0$. Such an $A$ is not unqiue.

Comment: How does this answer OP’s question?

Comment: @V.S.e.H. the property of $f$ worthy of attention is $f \circ f = 0$.

Comment: The question in particular is about the zero map: “ Is such transformation completely trivial, or does it possess any particular property worth noting? ” Also, it would be worthy to mention more about the matrices that satisfy $A^2=0$.

Comment: It is true that this answer does not address my specific question. However, it is an interesting comment on the problem. It didn't occur to me to use the matrix form $Ax = 0$ to observe any matrix such that $A^2 = 0$ satisfied the required property. That was illuminating. So although I don't think I can mark this as a correct answer, since its topic is tangential to my question, I still wanted to say thanks.